# use in in numpy.select condition

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use "in" in numpy.select.

```
x = np.arange(10)
condlist = [x in [2,3,4], x>5]
choicelist = [x, x**2]
np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `isin` instead:

```
x = np.arange(10)
condlist = [np.isin(x, [2,3,4]), x>5]
choicelist = [x, x**2]
np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  0,  2,  3,  4,  0, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```